# message is not shown

Tags: python, django

I am making a web site by seeing Django tutorial.But message in results.html is not shown.
results.html is

```
{% extends "polls/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block contents %}

 <h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
    <ul>
      {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
      <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'polls:polls_detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>

{% endblock contents %}
```

results.html inherits base.html.

base.html is

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">Tutorial</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="{% block nav_polls %}{% endblock %}"><a href="{% url 'polls:index' %}">polls</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">admin</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
　　　{% if messages %}
     {% bootstrap_messages messages %}
     {% endif %}
     {% block contents %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wanna show this part

```
<div class="container">
　{% if messages %}
 {% bootstrap_messages messages %}
 {% endif %}
 {% block contents %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

in results.html. Bootstrap in base.html is shown in results.html so I really cannot understand why  messages is not shown.views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Question
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,redirect
from .models import Choice
from .forms import MyForm
from .forms import VoteForm
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.views.generic.detail import SingleObjectMixin
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse



# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'polls/index.html',{
        'questions': Question.objects.all(),
    })


def vote(request,pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError,Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request,'polls/detail.html',{
            'question':question,
            'error_message':"You didn't select a choice",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
    # return redirect(reverse('polls:poll_results'), pk=pk)
    # return redirect('results_url', pk=pk)
    return redirect('polls:polls_results', pk=pk)


def results(request,pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Question,pk=pk)
    return render(request,'polls/results.html',{
        'question':obj,
    })

class FormTest(FormView):
   form_class = MyForm
   template_name = 'polls/form.html'
   success_url = reverse_lazy('polls:index')
form_test = FormTest.as_view()

class Detail(SingleObjectMixin,FormView):
    model = Question
    form_class = VoteForm
    context_object_name = 'question'
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['question'] = self.object
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.vote()
        choice = form.cleaned_data['choice']
        messages.success(self.request,'"%s"に投票しました' % choice)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return resolve_url('polls:results',self.kwargs['pk'])

detail = Detail.as_view()
```

I wanna show messages of

```
def form_valid(self, form):
            form.vote()
            choice = form.cleaned_data['choice']
            messages.success(self.request,'"%s"に投票しました' % choice)
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

How can I fix this?

My app directory is
[image: directory]

urls.py in polls is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views

app_name="polls"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='polls_detail'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/vote$', views.vote, name='poll_vote'),
    url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/results$', views.results, name='polls_results'),
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^form$', views.form_test),
]
```

I wanna call Detail class when results.html is loaded.

Comment: In your view, you're aren't passing `messages` as an argument to `render()`.

Comment: Are you developing locally? Or on a cloud IDE?

Comment: @JohnGordon Oh,really?Which render() do you think?

Comment: @csling Im developing locally.

Comment: what's your urls.py? it's not clear which view is being called that renders your template. Please show only the view that is responsible for rendering the template that (you're now showing us the code for 5 different views). Note that if your view is `results` then why do you expect `form_valid` to be called, it's not in your view?

Comment: @dirkgroten I updated my question.if u know something,please help me

Comment: can you specify what you are doing? Are you first going to a specific URL (which one), then posting some data and then hoping to see `results.html` with the success message? Is the `Detail` view rendered? tell us which URL you start with, what you do on that page and what URL you see as a result.